# Can you explain me bash command in details?

Tags: bash, git

I've got a long command in deploy script.

It seems that it checks the repository for changes, and if there are any, it runs 'npm run build' but something is not working right.

`(git diff -s --exit-code web/builder/ && test -d web/dist/js -a -d web/dist/css) || npm --prefix=web/builder run build_${SITE}`

Comment: *"... but something is not working right."* isn't really a helpful problem description.

Comment: Here's some reference material: [`git-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), [`test`](https://ss64.com/bash/test.html), [`npm run`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-run-script) and the [`&&`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists) operator.

Comment: @kapitansen: _explain in details ..._ : Which part of this code is it exactly, that you don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command consists of multiple parts:

> git diff -s --exit-code web/builder/

This command exits with `1` if there `web/builder/` changed and with `0` if not. Enter `man git-diff` in your terminal for details.

> test -d web/dist/js -a -d web/dist/css

This checks if `web/dist/js` and `web/dist/css` are both valid directories. Enter `man test` in your terminal for details.

> (git diff -s --exit-code web/builder/ && test -d web/dist/js -a -d web/dist/css)

This checks if `web/builder` has not changed and `web/dist/js` and `web/dist/css` are both valid directories.

> npm --prefix=web/builder run build_${SITE}

This is just an npm command.

> (git diff -s --exit-code web/builder/ && test -d web/dist/js -a -d web/dist/css) || npm --prefix=web/builder run build_${SITE}

This runs the npm command if the previous condition is `false`. This is the case if `web/builder` changed or `web/dist/js` is not a valid directory or `web/dist/css` is not a valid directory.

Answer (score 0):

So, the command looks like

```
(a && b) || c
```

Which means that if a is false, then b will not be evaluated, c will be evaluated instead due to the optimizations on logical operands. If a is true and b is false, then c will be evaluated (executed). If a and b are true, then c will not be evaluated.

So, let's see the parts:

## a: git diff -s --exit-code web/builder/

Checks whether there are differences. If so, the result will be 1 (true). Otherwise the result will be 0 (false). See

[image]

## b: test -d web/dist/js -a -d web/dist/css

This checks whether the paths are valid directories.

## c: npm --prefix=web/builder run build_${SITE}

This runs an `npm` command.

## Summary

If there are no differences on web/builder or web/dist/js and web/dist/css are not both valid directories, then an `npm` command will be executed.